# RefreshIndicator doesn't update ListView data

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to update a ListView using RefreshIndicator, but it is not working because the content is not updated. I load my screen with some initial data l and when the user scrolls down, I would like to load some extra items and add them to the top of my ListView. The request is working, but the screen is not up to date.

My code:

```
Widget _answerTab(User user) {
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
      future: _getFirstQuestions(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
            break;
          default:
            return RefreshIndicator(
                key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
                onRefresh: _refresh,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    itemCount: questions.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ExpandableCard();
                    }));
        }
      },
    );
  }

Future<void> _refresh() async {
    List<Question> nextQuestions =
        await QuestionHelper().getLastQuestions(_lastQuestionTimestamp);
    if (nextQuestions != null) {
      questions.insertAll(0, nextQuestions);
      _lastQuestionTimestamp = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(
          nextQuestions[nextQuestions.length - 1]
              .timestamp
              .millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _getFirstQuestions() async {
    questions = await QuestionHelper().getLastQuestions(_lastQuestionTimestamp);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call setState in your _refresh method to build your widget again.

```
setState(() {
    questions.insertAll(0, nextQuestions);
    _lastQuestionTimestamp = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(
        nextQuestions[nextQuestions.length - 1]
        .timestamp
        .millisecondsSinceEpoch
    );
});
```

Comment: I already tried this, but the list isn't updated. To see the new questions at the top of the list, I need to slide down and then up. Only after that the list is updated :(